# Drawing a line over some picture boxes in C#

Tags: c#, line, draw

I am developing a new application in C#, and I need some help.

I want to make this: Drawing a line OVER something. To be more specific, there are some picture-boxes which I generate them with code, and they are not visible at the start of the application.

This is an example if what I want:

[image]

And what I want like this:

[image]

The code that I am using for drawing the first line is this:

```
Graphics g;
Pen p;

void drawline(){
   g = this.CreateGraphics();
   p = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red, 15);
   g.DrawLine(p, new Point(10, 150), new Point(900, 150));
}
```

PS: I am sorry for the second line (it's drawn in [Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint) :)  )

Comment: I love the second line :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting picture boxes on you form, you could draw the images on you graphics before drawing the line.

```
g.DrawImage(image, point)
```

Maybee this could lead to something?

```
    Bitmap _bitmap = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height);

    Dictionary<int, Image> _images = new Dictionary<int, Image>();
    System.Drawing.Pen _redPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red, 15);
    bool _linePresent = false;

    int[] _imageIndex = { 1, 2, 1 };

    public void Init()
    {
        _images.Add(1, Image.FromFile("Melon.png"));
        _images.Add(2, Image.FromFile("Pineapple.png"));
        PictureBox1.Image = _bitmap;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmap);
        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        graphics.DrawImage(_images[_imageIndex[0]], 50, 100);
        graphics.DrawImage(_images[_imageIndex[1]], 350, 100);
        graphics.DrawImage(_images[_imageIndex[2]], 650, 100);

        if (_linePresent)
            graphics.DrawLine(_redPen, new Point(10, 150), new Point(900, 150));

    }
```

There could be some issues with updateing/refreshing the image. But i didn't test it.

Comment: I can't do that, because, the picture boxes are load randomly with some pictures, and if a statement is true, than i draw the line.

Comment: I would go for a bitmap and draw whenever i need it to update it. Then assign the bitmap to the Image property of 1 picturebox. This way you have BackPage rendering, and prevent flickering.

Comment: i can't use that, cause i have some loops with picture boxes which are matrix and i also have an image matrix..if i use that i BLOW everything...

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use a Rectangle (a label with red color) which is on top of the images. Much simpler than using graphics commands.

Comment: i have tried your ideea, but the label it's still NOT in front of the picture boxes , even if i used label1.bringtofront();...